# Invalid page requested during lifecycle of another page request (in IE and NOT in Firefox)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, page-lifecycle

Bear with me on this one!

Right.

Clicking on a link button on a page causes Postback to a page containing a number of controls.

For arguments sake say

- page a.aspx containing a link button

containing user controls

- control b.ascx
- control c.ascx

When clicked

- page d.aspx is requested.

During the Postback to (page a) on the server, (page d) is requested when using the IE browser (doesn't happen in Firefox) there are absolutely NO artefacts requested that live on (page d),  there are no response redirects or server transfers or anything referencing (page d).

The only thing I have seen like this is when an image or artefact is requested and  cant be found, or some pathing issues for an image, and this somehow screws the request up.

Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to resolve the problem is:

There was an asp:image element declared without its imageURL attribute set, setting it makes the problem go away.  Not declaring the attrbiute caused the default.aspx page in the application to be requested (when using IE).  I dont understand why this is the case. Is there something emitted to the client such that  the asp:image which, when the imageURL is not defined in IE, a GET request occurs?  Any definitive answers would be great.

Comment: I'm seeing something very similar where a post back on a page returns a blank page - but only in IE. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this...